# How can i add elements regularly in 100x100 zero matrix in python?

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
A=np.zeros((100, 100))
[(A[i][i+1]=(-10), A[i+1][i+1]=16, A[i+2][i+1]=(-10)) for i in range(0, 98, 1)]
```

```
    [(A[i][i+1]=(-10), A[i+1][i+1]=16, A[i+2][i+1]=(-10)) for i in range(0, 98, 1)]
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

[image]

M matrix is A(100x100 matrix) and, where -k = -10, d-k=6

how can i matrix 100x100 zero matrix into M matrix(Enter image up there) using an iteration?

Comment: An assignment `=` is a statement, statements cannot be used in list comprehensions like that. Only expressions can be used there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop for the general pattern, then manual set the corners

```
size = 10
d, k = 16, 10
A = np.zeros((size, size))
for i in range(1, size):
    A[i, i - 1] = -k
    A[i, i] = d
    A[i - 1, i] = -k
A[0, 0], A[size - 1, size - 1] = d - k, d - k
```

Result for `size, d, k = 10,16,10`

```
[[  6. -10.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [-10.  16. -10.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0. -10.  16. -10.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0. -10.  16. -10.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0. -10.  16. -10.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0. -10.  16. -10.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0. -10.  16. -10.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0. -10.  16. -10.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0. -10.  16. -10.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0. -10.   6.]]
```